# table name of column from view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a view which returns 30 columns. The view is created by inner join of three tables. I wish to find out which column was taken from which table using a query rather than going through the view line by line.
Is there a way to do that in sql server 2008?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wish to find out which column was taken from which table using a query rather than going through the view line by line

No, there isn't.

If the tables that the data came from are important, you can, in your view, use aliases to the columns to identify what tables they came from.

This will, however, negate the reason for having a view in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the execution plan XML for the column names and table names.

With this setup:

```
create table Table1
(
  Table1ID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(10)
)

create table Table2
(
  Table2ID int identity primary key,
  Table1ID int not null references Table1(Table1ID),
  Name varchar(10)
)

go

create view Table_1_2 as
select T1.Table1ID,
       T1.Name as Table1Name,
       T2.Name as Table2Name
from Table1 as T1
  inner join Table2 as T2
    on T1.Table1ID = T2.Table1ID
```

Execute a query against the view from SQL Server Management Studio with "Include Actual Execution Plan" enabled.

```
select *
from Table_1_2
where 0 = 1
```

Select the Execution plan tab, right click and select Show Execution Plan XML.
Copy the XML to a new query window, assign it to a XML variable and query the XML for the information you need.

```
declare @XML xml = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.2100.60" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="0" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" StatementSubTreeCost="1.57E-07" StatementText="select *&#xD;&#xA;from Table_1_2&#xD;&#xA;where 0 = 1" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xEBAD405D39FDCB6A" QueryPlanHash="0xAE962A4D575B83FE" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="0" CompileCPU="0" CompileMemory="112">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="25600" EstimatedPagesCached="25600" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="8" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="27" EstimateCPU="1.57E-07" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="0" LogicalOp="Constant Scan" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Constant Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.57E-07">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[xx]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Table1]" Alias="[T1]" Column="Table1ID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[xx]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Table1]" Alias="[T1]" Column="Name" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[xx]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[Table2]" Alias="[T2]" Column="Name" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <ConstantScan />
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>';

with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')
select T.N.value('@Table', 'sysname') as TableName,
       T.N.value('@Column', 'sysname') as ColumnName
from @XML.nodes('//ColumnReference') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
TableName            ColumnName           
-------------------- -------------------- 
[Table1]             Table1ID             
[Table1]             Name                 
[Table2]             Name
```